# How can I compare (equality) of two elements of same Set in Coq?

Tags: coq

```
Inductive ty: Set :=
| I
| O.

Definition f (x: ty) (y: ty): nat :=
  if x = y then 0 else 1.
```

I want the function `f` to compare two terms of type `ty` but it does not compile and I see this error:

> The term `x = y` has type `Prop` which is not a (co-)inductive type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to prove that equality is decidable for `ty` (which can be done automatically using `decide equality`) and then use that definition in the `if ... then ... else ...` statement. Concretely:

```
Inductive ty: Set :=
| I
| O.

Definition ty_eq_dec : forall (x y : ty), { x = y } + { x <> y }.
Proof.
decide equality.
Defined.

Definition f (x: ty) (y: ty): nat :=
  if ty_eq_dec x y then 0 else 1.
```

Comment: Can you tell me a bit more about { } + { }. I thought it to be like Proposition1 or Prop2. But it doesn't work that way. Is there something like `split` for them?

Comment: @abhishek See [sumbool](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Bool.Sumbool.html). More explanations in e.g. [this blog post](http://seb.mondet.org/blog/post/coqtests-02-sumbools.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `match` to compare the elements of inductive data types.

```
Definition f x y := match x,y with I, I | O, O => 0 | _,_ => 1 end.
```

`decide equality` is a more general tactic and works for infinite sets, but it is good to know that it is `match` that is doing the real work.

Comment: You could improve this answer by noting that this function satisfies forall x y, f x y = 0 <-> x = y and that can be proved quite easily in this case.